# I keep getting an error on the opening bracket of my main function with the message obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN11linked_listC1Ev':|

Tags: c++

I've tried compiling in Visual Studio and CodeBlocks and I've received different error messages from both. I've been working at trying to solve this one issue for several hours and would greatly appreciate the help. I'm just trying to write a simple linked list program.

This is my Header file:

```
   #ifndef LINKED_LIST_H_INCLUDED
    #define LINKED_LIST_H_INCLUDED
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstdio>
    #include<cstdlib>
    using namespace std;

    /*
    * Node Declaration
    */
    struct node
    {
        int info;
        struct node *next;
    }*start;

    /*
     * Class Declaration
     */
    class linked_list
    {
        public:
            node* create_node(int);
            void insert_begin();
            void insert_last();
            void insert_pos();
            void delete_pos();
            void delete_begin();
            void delete_last();
            void display();

            linked_list()
            {
                start = NULL;
            }
    };


    #endif // LINKED_LIST_H_INCLUDED
```

Here is my implementation file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include "linked_list.h"
using namespace std;

/*
 * Create Node
 */
node *linked_list::create_node(int value)
{
    struct node *temp, *s;
    temp = new(struct node);
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Memory not allocated "<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->info = value;
        temp->next = NULL;
        return temp;
    }
}

/*
 * Display all the elements of the linked list
 */

void linked_list::display()
{
    struct node *temp;
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"The List is Empty"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    temp = start;
    cout<<"Elements of list are: "<<endl;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->info<<"->";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
}

/*
 * Inserting at the beginning of the list
 */
void linked_list::insert_begin()
{
    int value;
    cout<<"Enter the value to be inserted: ";
    cin>>value;
    struct node *temp, *p;
    temp = create_node(value);
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        start = temp;
        start->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        p = start;
        start = temp;
        start->next = p;
    }
    cout<<"Element Inserted at beginning"<<endl;
}

/*
 * Inserting Node at the end of the list
 */
void linked_list::insert_last()
{
    int value;
    cout<<"Enter the value to be inserted: ";
    cin>>value;
    struct node *temp, *s;
    temp = create_node(value);
    s = start;
    while (s->next != NULL)
    {
        s = s->next;
    }
    temp->next = NULL;
    s->next = temp;
    cout<<"Element Inserted at last position"<<endl;
}

/*
 * Insertion of node at the specified position
 */
void linked_list::insert_pos()
{
    int value, pos, counter = 0;
    cout<<"Enter the value to be inserted: ";
    cin>>value;
    struct node *temp, *s, *ptr;
    temp = create_node(value);
    cout<<"Enter the position at which node to be inserted: ";
    cin>>pos;
    int i;
    s = start;
    while (s != NULL)
    {
        s = s->next;
        counter++;
    }
    if (pos == 1)
    {
        if (start == NULL)
        {
            start = temp;
            start->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr = start;
            start = temp;
            start->next = ptr;
        }
    }
    else if (pos > 1  && pos <= counter)
    {
        s = start;
        for (i = 1; i < pos; i++)
        {
            ptr = s;
            s = s->next;
        }
        ptr->next = temp;
        temp->next = s;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Position out of range"<<endl;
    }
}


/*
 * Deletion element at a given position
 */
void linked_list::delete_pos()
{
    int pos, i, counter = 0;
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"List is empty"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    cout<<"Enter the position of value to be deleted: ";
    cin>>pos;
    struct node *s, *ptr;
    s = start;
    if (pos == 1)
    {
        start = s->next;
    }
    else
    {
        while (s != NULL)
        {
            s = s->next;
            counter++;
        }
        if (pos > 0 && pos <= counter)
        {
            s = start;
            for (i = 1;i < pos;i++)
            {
                ptr = s;
                s = s->next;
            }
            ptr->next = s->next;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Position out of range"<<endl;
        }
        free(s);
        cout<<"Element Deleted"<<endl;
    }
}
/*
 * Deletion of element at the beginning of the list
 */
void linked_list::delete_begin()
{

    struct node *temp, *p;
    temp = start;
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"List is empty"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        p = start;
        start = temp;
        p=start->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    cout<<"Element deleted at beginning"<<endl;
}
/*
 * Deletion of element at the end of the list
 */
void linked_list::delete_last()
{
    struct node *p, *s;
    s = start;
    while (s->next != NULL)
    {
        p = s;
        s = s->next;
    }
    p->next = NULL;
    delete s;
    cout<<"Element deleted at last position"<<endl;
}
```

And Here is my driver file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include "linked_list.h"
using namespace std;


main()
{
    int choice, nodes, element, position, i;
    linked_list linlist;
    start = NULL;
    while (1)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"---------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<"Linked List Homework Menu"<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<"---------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"1.Insert Node at the Beginning of the List"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.Insert Node at the Last Position in the List"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.Insert Node at Specified Position"<<endl;
        cout<<"4.Delete Node at Specified Position"<<endl;
        cout<<"5.Delete Node at the Last Position in the List"<<endl;
        cout<<"6.Delete Node at the Beginning of the List"<<endl;
        cout<<"7.Display Linked List"<<endl;
        cout<<"8.Exit "<<endl;
        cout<<"Please enter a selection : ";
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout<<"Inserting Node at the Beginning: "<<endl;
            linlist.insert_begin();
            cout<<endl;
            break;

        case 2:
            cout<<"Inserting Node at the Last Position: "<<endl;
            linlist.insert_last();
            cout<<endl;
            break;

        case 3:
            cout<<"Inserting Node at a Specific Position:"<<endl;
            linlist.insert_pos();
            cout<<endl;
            break;

        case 4:
            cout<<"Deleting Node at a Specific Position: "<<endl;
            linlist.delete_pos();
            break;

        case 5:
            cout<<"Deleting Node at the Last Position: "<<endl;
            linlist.delete_last();
            break;

        case 6:
            cout<<"Deleting Node at the Beginning: "<<endl;
            linlist.delete_begin();
            break;

        case 7:
            cout<<"Display the linked list"<<endl;
            linlist.display();
            cout<<endl;
            break;

        case 8:
            cout<<"Exiting Program... Goodbye!"<<endl;
            exit(1);
            break;

        default:
            cout<<"Option not viable"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is encountered when the compiler gets to line 10 in the driver file. I'll put both error lists from Visual Studio and CodeBlocks below. I'm still grasping C++ so thanks in advance to anyone who decides to help!

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stssa.png)
[Other Error Log](https://imgur.com/a/PpOxQAP)

Comment: why are you including `<cstdlib>` and `<cstdio>`? Don't use `using namespace` in header files!

Comment: It's __`int main()`__.

Comment: `linked_list() { start = NULL; }` don't use global variables. If a `linked_list` has a `start` then declare it as a member and use the initializer list of the constructor to set its value.

Comment: Don't use `exit()` to end a C++ program. No stack unwinding will occur if you do so. To exit from `main()` indicating an error `return EXIT_FAILURE;`.

Comment: `insert_begin()` is usually called `push_front()`, `inset_last()` --> `push_back()`, `insert_pos()` --> `insert()` (why does your `insert_pos()` not take a paramter to specify, where a value should be inserted?), `delete_pos()` --> `remove()` (again: why no parameter?), `delete_begin()` --> `pop_front()`, `delete_last()` --> `pop_back()`.

Comment: Also, your implementation violates the [Rule of three, five, zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: Sorry, I’m still very new to C++ and I appreciate the help and feedback. I’ll try reformatting based on your recommendations. Also I fixed the last error but now I get an error LNK2005 “struct node * start (?start@@3PAUnode@@A) already defined in main.obj     And LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found

Comment: Show your current code in your question.

Comment: It’s almost unchanged except I added an int to Main() making it int Main() which cleared up the other errors. I want to sort out the errors and get it in a working state and then reformat everything and check for logic errors

Comment: You can't declare variables in your header file.  Make `start` a member variable.

Answer (score 0):

**The first error**:

```
struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *next;
}*start;
```

You created non-const variable in heaader file. Then this header was included in two source files.
Eventually, you have two variables called 'start' in two object files. That`s why linker throws an error "multiple definition of start".

As was mentioned in the comments, 'start' variable must be moved to linked_list class.

**The second error**:

```
main()
```

should be

```
int main()
```